# update data from a dataset to the database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

the remove button actually removes the data from the dataset but when i restart the program it just reappears, tried with "Me.testTableAdapter.Fill(Me.testDataSet.test)", searched a lot and still didnt find anything. any help appreciated!

here is the code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As OleDbConnection
    Dim com As OleDbCommand
    Dim txtconnesione As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\test.mdb"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: questa riga di codice carica i dati nella tabella 'testDataSet.test'. È possibile spostarla o rimuoverla se necessario.
        Me.INATableAdapter.Fill(Me.testDataSet.test)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        con = New OleDbConnection(txtconnesione)
        com = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO INA (CODICE,Interno,esterno,altezza) VALUES(@CODICE,@Interno,@esterno,@altezza)", con)
        con.Open()
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODICE", txtcodice.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interno", txtinterno.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@esterno", txtesterno.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@altezza", txtaltezza.Text)
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("New Record")
        Me.testTableAdapter.Fill(Me.testDataSet.test)
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
            DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row)
            testDataSet.test.DataSet.AcceptChanges()


        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you specified any delete command on INATableAdapter?  If so, what is it? if not, that will likely be the issue.  Guessing Button2 is the Delete record button, you may want to consider naming your controls so it's clear to you when it comes to maintaining what everything does

Comment: yeah that's the problem: i don't know a delete command for the INATableAdapter. I mean it actually deletes it from the datagrid but it doesn't "update"

Comment: Well, not trying to sound unhelp but probably means you've got some reading to do. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/directly-access-the-database-with-a-tableadapter?view=vs-2022 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/delete-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: @Hursey thank you for the links, the problem is that im not using C#, im using C